# Creating a HTML element with attributes in jQuery, failing in ie7 and ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am generating a HTML element with an attribute via jQuery and then inserting it into the DOM. I am passing a class attribute into the element. See below:

```
jQuery('<li></li>', {  
    class: "myClass" 
});
```

I am receiving the following error in ie7 and ie8, on the line with `class: "myCLass"`.

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number
```

It works in ie9 and Firefox. Haven't tested any other browsers.

Is this method of generating an element with attributes not supported in ie7 and ie8? Or am I making a mistake in my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is reserved. Use `className` or wrap it with quotes.

Comment: To be more specific, you can't use `class` as the key. You can, however, use `"class"` or rename it to `className`.

Comment: wrapping in quotes fixed the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `className`, or use `prop`.

```
// jQuery way
$('<div></div>').prop('class', 'myClass')

// Vanilla js way
$('<div></div>')[0].className = 'myClass'
```